# How do I implement intellisense support for a custom DLR language in VS2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, dynamic-language-runtime

I have just started writing my first language for the .NET DLR.

I would like to know if it is possible to extend Visual Studio 2008 IntelliSense to handle the syntax of a custom DLR language?

**EDIT:** I have decided to bypass VS2008 and target VS2010 instead. See accepted answer for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio's primary extensibility method for supporting new languages is through [Language Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165099.aspx) in a [VSPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166424.aspx).

Visual Studio 2010 has ***radically*** improved the ability to support a new language, but if target your extension to it you will not be able to use it in older versions. If you write a language service for Visual Studio 2008, you'll be able to use it with Visual Studio 2010 as well. Unless you have some *strong* financial ties to supporting Visual Studio 2008, definitely skip it and go for 2010.

Here is the best public link I know of right now:

- [Django Editor in VS 2010 – Part 1 (Colors)](http://www.hill30.com/MikeFeingoldBlog/index.php/2009/07/31/django-editor-in-vs-2010-part-1-colors/) (This is the first entry of a 7-part series on his blog.)

I'm working on a new set of articles about support for Visual Studio 2010, but they aren't ready yet, and likely won't be for a while. :\ If you decide to go with a Visual Studio 2008 language service, I have several entries on [my blog](http://blog.280z28.org/) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have decided to bypass VS2008 and target VS2010 instead.

Comment: How do i get in contact with you? I dont see an email on your blog or SO profile. You can email me by using the email in my SO profile.